# Confidence interval of MLE variance estimator (Normal Distribution)

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood

May I use Fisher information for constructing confidence interval for MLE variance estimator?

Fisher information should be: $I(\theta) = E[I_0(\theta,Y)] = E\left[ \frac{m}{2(\sigma^2)^2} \right] = \frac{m}{2(\sigma^2)^2}$

Variance of estimated parametr is : $V(\hat{\theta}) = I(\theta)^{-1} = \frac{2(\sigma^2)^2}{m}$

Supposing the sample size is large enough, may I use following equation for 95% CI?
$$
\sigma^2 \in \hat{\theta} \pm z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \sqrt{V(\hat{\theta})}
$$

Comment: The sampling distribution of $\sigma^2$ [follows a $\chi^2$ distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/121662), not a standard normal. Note that the $\chi^2$ distribution is not symmetric (which means the confidence interval cannot be written $\pm$ some value). The 95% confidence interval for your estimate of $\sigma^2$ should look [something like this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/338447).

Comment: You may, but you'll need a pretty substantial sample size - in the hundreds - for that to be (reasonably, IMO) accurate.  As @Durden says, we know the exact sampling distribution of $\sigma^2$ in this case, so you'd do better to use that.